# Amcharts 3 pie chart loads incorrectly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amcharts

I'm building a pie chart on a dashboard, and for some reason the initial load seems to be correct for a split second, before it reverts to something else. (The chart seems to reload even though I did not call for it) The html is the same for other charts that are working fine, as is the code on the javascript for makechart(). I really can't seem to understand why this is happening.

If I zoom in/zoom out the chart changes to show what it's supposed to be, and the incorrect image no longer appears. However, it should display the correct chart image directly instead of requiring this sort of manual manipulation.

I can't seem to post images so I have included a link to the git issue that I raised with the images attached: https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts3/issues/237

Update: I've since found out that it is an issue with amcharts 3 responsive plugin. I'm currently trying a fix by overriding the rules for minHeight: 0, but let me know if any of you are able to come up with a better solution.